# getting run time error in my C# code

Tags: c#, .net

1.i have to get input and store it to dictionary, and again get some input and check whether it is in dictionary or not.
2. I have tried this but giving the error (input string was not in correct format).
3. its not giving any error at compile time,but it is giving error at run time.whats the problem with this.
4. my inputs are: - 
        3
        sam 99912222
        tom 11122222
        harry 12299933
        sam
        edward
        harry
5. In place of Read(). I have also tried ReadLine(), but the problem is same.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{
    static void Main()
    {

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        Dictionary<string, int> phbook = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string name = Console.Read().ToString();
            int phonno = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            phbook.Add(name, phonno);
        }

        foreach (var keypairs in phbook)
        {
            string namet = Console.Read().ToString();
            if (phbook.ContainsKey(namet))
            {
                Console.Write("{0}={1}", namet, phbook[namet]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Not found");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

---

The complete error is

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) [0x00057] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00015] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x00008] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.String value) [0x0000b] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at Solution.Main () [0x00034] in solution.cs:15 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) [0x00057] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00015] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x00008] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.String value) [0x0000b] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at Solution.Main () [0x00034] in solution.cs:15
```

Comment: What was your input?

Comment: something u input by `Console.ReadLine()` might not able to convert to int

Comment: @HiranPerera i have re edited the question with inputs.

Comment: Get the whole line by ReadLine() and substring it from the last index of spaces. Could you please try that out and let me know

Comment: It is better practice to put edits under *Edit* heading so that already active users of the thread don't have to scroll though whole question content again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Console.Read()` returns *single char*, that's why

```
 string name = Console.Read().ToString();
```

looks very suspecious; another issue is that not every string is a correct integer value (`"bla-bla-bla"` being an example):

```
 int phonno = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Let's re-write the fragment:

```
 // We want name (string), say "Test" not just character 'T'
 string name = Console.ReadLine();

 int phonno = 0;

 // Ask for a number until a correct one is provided
 while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out phonno)) {
   Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number, please put the number again."); 
 }
```

The same amendment with `string namet = Console.Read().ToString();` it should be

```
 // We want name (string), say "Test" not just character 'T'
 string namet = Console.ReadLine();
```

**Edit:** What's going on

You put `sam 99912222` and execute

```
string name = Console.Read().ToString();
int phonno = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

`Console.Read()` reads just the *first character* `'s'` (not `"sam"`) and the other part `"am"` is read by `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`. Sure `"am"` is not a *valid integer* and you have the exception.

Comment: @Dimitry Bychenko please review the question I have re edited it.

Answer (score 0):

May be an extra space or character being inserted after you hit enter. So you should remove that space or extra character like

```
int phonno = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
```

Give it a try and it should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Console.ReadLine()`

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

or you can use `int.TryParse` like below:

```
Int32 n=0;
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);
```

it will handle the exception internally, it will return by default value 0 if any exception found into conversion.

you can read more about `int.TryParse` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) :

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It is better to get an exception than to let framework swallow it. I would go with `Convert.ToInt32` instead of `int.TryParse`.